# Mysql replace field from another table's field

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to replace the Table1's filed values from Table2's values while select query.

Eg:

Table1:

```
Org                  Permission
--------------------------------------
Company1             1,3,7
Company2             1,3,8
```

Table2:

```
Permission          Permission
--------------------------------------
1                   Read
3                   Write
7                   Execute
8                   Delete
```

I need like this:

```
Org                  Permission
--------------------------------------
Company1             Read,Write,Execute
Company2             Read,Write,Delete
```

Comment: Read about database normalization.

Comment: Use replace() http://phptooltip.blogspot.in/2013/05/replacestrfromstrtostr.html

Comment: -1 Please don't keep entering the same question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710990/oracle-replace-function) over and over again - instead, try improving your existing question.

Answer (score 0):

I have been following your post since it was tagged in Oracle :D

In oracle it was looking in much possible ways, But in mysql you have to follow it with the help of procedure:

Schema:

```
create table table1 (org varchar(50), permission_id varchar(50));
create table table2 (permission_id int, permission_name varchar(50));

insert into table1 values ('Company1','1,3,7'),('Company2','1,3,8');
insert into table2 values (1,'Read'),(3,'Write'),(7,'Execute'),(8,'Delete');
```

Procedure:

```
    DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Update_Table_data`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `Update_Table_data`()
BEGIN
    declare max_row int;
    declare p1 int;
    Set p1 = 0;
    SET max_row = (SELECT max(@i:=@i+1) AS row_num FROM table2 AS t,(SELECT @i:=0) AS foo);

    label1: LOOP
    set p1 = p1 + 1;
    IF p1 <= max_row THEN
        UPDATE Table1
        SET permission_id = 
        replace(permission_id, (select permission_id from 
                    (SELECT @i:=@i+1 AS row_num ,t.* FROM table2 AS t,(SELECT @i:=0) AS foo) a
                    where row_num = p1), 
            (select permission_name from 
            (SELECT @i:=@i+1 AS row_num ,t.* FROM table2 AS t,(SELECT @i:=0) AS foo) a
            where row_num = p1));       
        Iterate label1;
    END IF;    
        LEAVE label1;
    END LOOP label1;
    -- SET @x = p1;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

and then make a call to update your values :

```
call Update_Table_data;
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

See [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb7cd9/2) for initial data and this is resultant data [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99569/1)

```
UPDATE 
    organization
SET 
    permisson = (SELECT 
                   GROUP_CONCAT(VALUE) 
                 FROM 
                  ( SELECT 
                      org,
                      SUBSTRING_INDEX(permisson,',',1) AS `permisson`
                    FROM 
                      organization 

                    UNION 

                    SELECT
                      org,
                      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(permisson,',',2),',',-1) AS `permisson` 
                     FROM 
                    organization

                    UNION 

                    SELECT
                      org,
                      SUBSTRING_INDEX(permisson,',',-1) AS `permisson` 
                    FROM 
                      organization
                   ) AS t 

                   JOIN 

                   permission p 

                   WHERE 
                    p.p_id = t.permisson AND 
                    t.org = organization.org 
                   GROUP BY org
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace your numbers using REPLACE.It work properly only when you are using single digit values for permission.

```
    SQL = " SELECT Org, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Permission,"1","Read'"),"3","Write'"),"7","Execute'"),"8","Delete'") as Permission FROM myTable "
```

[REPLACE()](http://phptooltip.blogspot.in/2013/05/replacestrfromstrtostr.html)

Comment: Is there any reason for down vote?Is not working?