# I want to remove the special symbol from string?

Tags: plsql

**I want to remove the symbol **Rℸblock**
SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE(description, '[^0-9A-Za-z .]', '') FROM emp A WHERE emp_id='12344';
Rℸ

Comment: OK; what's the question? You posted select statement, but didn't say anything about it. Does it work? Does it not work? Raises an error? If so, which one? Consider posting sample data that illustrates the problem, as well as desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```sql
Select Replace('abc_Rℸ_def_Rℸ_ghi', 'Rℸ', '') "COL" From Dual

/*  R e s u l t :
COL                
-------------------
abc__def__ghi   */
```

... 'Rℸ' removed (replaced with empty string)
Or ...

```sql
Select Replace('abc_Rℸ_def_Rℸ_ghi', 'Rℸ', 'XXX') "COL" From Dual

/*  R e s u l t :
COL                
-------------------
abc_XXX_def_XXX_ghi   */
```

... 'Rℸ' replaced with 'XXX'
**Addition**:
If there are not too many different symbols that should be removed You could define them in a cte and use nested Replace() functions.  Here is the code removing 3 symbols from strings:

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
  tbl AS
    ( Select 1 "ID", 'abc_Rℸ_def_°_ghi_@_jkl' "TXT" From Dual Union All
      Select 2 "ID", 'abc_def_°_ghi_jkl' "TXT" From Dual Union All
      Select 3 "ID", 'abc_Rℸ_def_°_ghi_jkl' "TXT" From Dual 
    ),
  symbols AS
    ( Select '°' "S1" ,'@' "S2", 'Rℸ' "S3" From Dual  
    )
```

```sql
--  M a i n    S Q L :
Select  ID, TXT, 
        Replace( Replace( Replace(TXT, S1, ''
                                 )
                          , S2, ''
                        )
                , S3, ''
               ) "TXT_2"
From tbl
Inner Join symbols s ON(1 = 1)
```

```sql
/*    -- R e s u l t :
  ID  TXT                        TXT_2                    
----  -------------------------  -------------------------
   1    abc_Rℸ_def_°_ghi_@_jkl   abc__def__ghi__jkl
   2    abc_def_°_ghi_jkl        abc_def__ghi_jkl
   3    abc_Rℸ_def_°_ghi_jkl     abc__def__ghi_jkl       */
```

Comment: We are having multiple symbols like lamda, delta , beta and so on .
I want to remove all different symbols

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947623/multiple-replace-function-in-oracle

Answer (score 0):

We can use

select  regexp_replace(column_name,'[^[:alpha:]\s.,;:!? - " .0-9!@#~%^%{}&*()$¶±-]','') from dual;