# How to replace multiple matching patterns with multiple specified replacement strings in SQL - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

We have varchar2(250) column that have various text data we want to replace with other specific text.
Note: I do not want to use multiple replace function for this requirement, is there is any better way to do it

**requirement is to:**

```
Replace <   with    "less than"
Replace >   With    "greater than"
Replace &   With    and
```

For example data in table is:

```
"amount must be < 1 & > 2"
```

Output of SQL should be:

```
"amount must be greater than 1 and less than 2"
```

Comment: is that one column data ?

Comment: What's the problem with `REPLACE` when it is what meant for this?

Comment: Yes, this is one column data, for solution please use dual and sample text above

Comment: The problem with this is we need to replace 15 to 20 characters with string value

Comment: "*I do not want to use multiple replace function*" - why? What is the real problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: @DeepakKhatri I've added the answer on the duplicate question. I'm almost sure this question will not be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

According to me you have to use 3 replacement statements. Somthing like this:-

```
SELECT REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE ('amount must be < 1 & > 2', '<', 'less than'), '>' ,'greater than'), '&', 'and')
FROM DUAL;
```

I think this is only the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use **REPLACE** thrice, that isn't a lot of effort.

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 'amount must be < 1 & > 2' str FROM dual
  3  )
  4  SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(str, '<', 'less than'), '&','and'),'>','greater than') str
  5  FROM DATA
  6  /

STR
---------------------------------------------
amount must be less than 1 and greater than 2

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `replace` function

```
SELECT Replace(
          Replace(
            Replace(a, '>', 'greater than'), 
                              '<', 'lesser than'),
                                           '&', 'and')
FROM   Yourtable
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8d29c/2)